# Swift merge multipe publisher into single publisher

Tags: swift, combine

So I have to listeners on the database that fire when there's updates.

```
func listenToAltersForUser(userId: String) async -> PassthroughSubject<[AlterModel], Never> { ...

func listenForUpdates() -> PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never> { ....
```

I'd like to map both of these publishers to a single publisher of

```
AnyPublisher<[AlterUIModel], Never>
```

Here's what I currently have

```
func invoke(userId: String, lastAlterId: String?) async -> AnyPublisher<[AlterUIModel], Never> {
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<[AlterUIModel], Never>()
        
        let alterStream = await alterRepository.listenToAltersForUser(userId: userId)
        let frontRecordUpdates = frontRepository.listenForUpdates()
        let altersPublisher = alterStream.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        let frontRecordsPublisher = frontRecordUpdates.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        return altersPublisher.combineLatest(frontRecordsPublisher) { alters, frontUpdates in
            Task.detached {
                let altersUIModels = await alters.asyncMap { alter in
                    let frontRecord = await self.frontRepository.getLastFrontRecordForAlter(alterId: alter.id)
                    let isFronting = frontRecord != nil && frontRecord?.endTime == nil
                    return AlterUIModel(
                        fromAlterModel: alter,
                        isFronting: isFronting,
                        frontingDate: frontRecord?.endTime ?? frontRecord?.startTime
                    )
                }
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

What I can't get around is the async nature of this, and the fact that only one of the publishers emits values saying that *something* is updated.

EDIT: I've switched to `AsyncStream` and have the following

```
func invoke(userId: String, lastAlterId: String?) async {
        AsyncStream([AlterUIModel].self) { cont in
            let alterStream = await alterRepository.listenToAltersForUser(userId: userId)
            let frontRecordStream = frontRepository.listenForUpdates()
            for await (alters, _) in combineLatest(alterStream, frontRecordStream) {
                let alters = await alters.asyncMap { alter in
                    let frontRecord = await frontRepository.getLastFrontRecordForAlter(alterId: alter.id)
                    let isFronting = frontRecord != nil && frontRecord?.endTime == nil
                    return AlterUIModel(
                        fromAlterModel: alter,
                        isFronting: isFronting,
                        frontingDate: frontRecord?.endTime ?? frontRecord?.startTime
                    )
                }
                return alters
            }
        }
    }
```

with the error

```
Cannot pass function of type '(AsyncStream<[AlterUIModel]>.Continuation) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
```

What I'm unsure is how to return the combined stream. I tried wrapping it in another AysyncStream, but it didn't like that. Any thoughts?

Comment: May be it's time to migrate to Concurrency?

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm transitioning from Android to iOS so I'm not quite sure what you mean there.

Comment: So the trick here is that `combineLatest` doesn't let me use concurrency, but I still need to subscribe to updates?

Comment: You already have `Task.detached` and `await ...` why to use `erraseToAnyPublisher`? Just return `async` result.

Comment: Becuase it's not a one-time query. It's a subscription to database changes, so I need some kind of subscription.

Comment: You can use `AsyncStream` and `for await loop` for that.

Comment: Mixing Combine and Swift Concurrency (aka async/await) is a code smell.  If you were going to use Swit Concurrency, then In your previous question (about creating a `PassthroughSubject`) you may have asked how to convert the messages from your server into an `AsyncSequence` that way you could use one concurrency model instead of mixing them.  I can try to write a sample in a bit.

Comment: You need an AsyncStream not combine. Don’t mix the 2

Comment: I've edited the original quesiton with my latest use case. I'm unsure how to return the combined result from here.

Comment: We need a Minimal Reproducible Example, we are guessing on what is truly being returned from your repository, it would be best to get rid of combine all together

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I got it working!

```
func invoke(userId: String, lastAlterId: String?) -> AsyncStream<[AlterUIModel]> {
        return AsyncStream([AlterUIModel].self) { cont in
            Task {
                let alterStream = await alterRepository.listenToAltersForUser(userId: userId)
                let frontRecordStream = frontRepository.listenForUpdates()
                for await (alters, _) in combineLatest(alterStream, frontRecordStream) {
                    let alters = await alters.asyncMap { alter in
                        let frontRecord = await frontRepository.getLastFrontRecordForAlter(alterId: alter.id)
                        let isFronting = frontRecord != nil && frontRecord?.endTime == nil
                        return AlterUIModel(
                            fromAlterModel: alter,
                            isFronting: isFronting,
                            frontingDate: frontRecord?.endTime ?? frontRecord?.startTime
                        )
                    }
                    cont.yield(alters)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always hold on to the task, what happens if the stream gets cancelled? How does the inner task get cancelled?